# why does &(std::to_wstring()) return an empty string?

Tags: c++, windows-runtime

I'm trying to convert an `int` to a `wstring*` using the `std::to_wstring` function in a C++/CX app for Windows.

#### The following does NOT work:

```
wstring* turn = &(to_wstring(50));               //the value of *turn is ""
```

#### This however does:

```
wstring tu = to_wstring(50);
wstring* turn = &tu;                             //the value of *turn is "50"
```

Could someone explain why? Shouldn't both code snippets show the exact same behaviour?

Comment: The first one should not even compile, but it's a Visual C++ bug

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`to_wstring(50)` is a temporary. Temporaries are destroyed at the end of the full-expression (*i.e.*, just after the semicolon). So after the first snippet runs, `turn` points to some memory that no longer contains a valid `std::wstring`, since it has already been destroyed.

In the second snippet, the temporary `to_wstring(50)` is *copied* into the variable `tu`. The temporary is destroyed, but `tu` is not, since it's still in scope.

Comment: That seems to make a lot of sense, thank you very much!